# update the corresponding field with current date function Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, datetime

I `need to remove the duplicate from the following table` and update.

**Table : product**  -  Fields

```
s.no   P_name    cost   code     date of purchase

1      pen       5      pen1     12/05/2012

2      pencill   6      pncl     13/05/2015

3      pen       10     pen      14/05/2015
```

I need the output as highest cost and the latest date it purchased in another table

**Table : Product_result**  -  Fields

```
s.no   P_name     cost    code     date of purchase

1      pen        10      pen      14/05/2015

2      pencil     6       pncll    13/05/2015
```

Removed the duplicate by

```
insert into Product_result(P_name) select product.P_name from product
group by p_name having count(*) >1;
```

Now I have to update remaining fields by

```
insert into product_result(COST,DATE_OF_PURCHASE) select product (MRP,RECHARGE_DATE_TIME) 
where MRP = MAX(MRP) &&  EVENT_START_DATE > NOW();
```

I need to get the maximum mrp and recent valve together.

Comment: Why would you change the `s.no` column?

Comment: No need to change the s.no column. its auto incremental

Answer (score 0):

insert into Product_result
select s_no,p_name,max(cost),code,max(date of purchase)
from product
group by s_no

Comment: Condition in which i need row with max(cost)&&max(dateofpurchace). Both the condition should be satisfied.  Vinay h

Answer (score 0):

Answer :

```
 Update product_result as a inner join product as b on b.p_name=a.p_name set b.cost=a.cost,b.code=a.code,b.date of purchase=a.date of purchase where date of purchase <= now() and (Select max(cost));
```